# fullCalendar only sees JSON with one data set

Tags: javascript, json, python-2.7, fullcalendar

I pass my HTML the result of a Python json.dumps that contains multiple records i.e.

```
[{'title':'xxx','start':'2018-01-01'},{'title':'ccc','start':'2018-01-02'}]
```

In the HTML the JS starts with

```
var data = jQuery.parseJSON('{{caldata | safe}}'); 
var events; 
events = []; 
events.push(data);
```

In the fullCalendar options I have events: events

When I pass 1 event it works correctly, displaying the event on the proper day on the calendar. When I pass multiple events no events are displayed.

I have looked at the data being passed using print to console it looks to be correctly formatted.

Do I need to do a loop to parse through the data?  I have checked multiple examples and articles and can't find examples of that being needed but I 'm certainly missing something.

Answer (score 0):

If `data` is an array, you either have to loop through it or can just set `events` to `data`

Example 1 (loop):

```
var data = jQuery.parseJSON('{{caldata | safe}}'); 
var events; 
events = []; 
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    events.push(data[i]);
}
```

Example 2 (Preferred):

```
var data = jQuery.parseJSON('{{caldata | safe}}'); 
var events; 
events = data;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I tried both styles and could not get any events to appear - makes me think my JSON is somehow not correct - I do the following in Python to prepare and send the data: c.execute(query)
    caldata1 = [dict(title=row[2],start=str(row[3])+"T"+str(row[4]),end=str(row[3])+"T"+str(row[7])) for row in c.fetchall()]     caldata = json.dumps(caldata1) return render_template('calendar_display.html',caldata=caldata)     Am I missing something there?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with jQuery.parseJson, but why are passing '{{caldata | safe}}' as the input instead of the simple json-string?

Comment: Also take a look at the jQuery docs: "As of jQuery 3.0, $.parseJSON is deprecated. To parse JSON strings use the native JSON.parse method instead." Link: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Comment: I'm a beginner and may have taken a bad path - I am trying to take data that I pull from MYSQL in Python and send it to fullCalendar - to do that I query MYSQL, read those records into a list of dictionary's [{'title':'xxx','start':'2018-01-01'},{'title':'ccc','start':'2018-01-02'}]. I then use json.dumps on the data as it is passed to the HTML template (return render_template('calendar_display.html',caldata=json.dumps(caldata))) and then use the code above in JS to process it.  Am I off base in my strategy?  If so any detailed guidance would be very appreciated.